# Python 2.7 Yahoo Finance No Definition Found

Tags: python, yql, yahoo-api, yahoo-finance

Hope you are well. I'm Using Python 2.7 and new at it. I'm trying to use yahoo finance API to get information from stocks, here is my code:

```
from yahoo_finance import Share
yahoo = Share('YHOO')
print yahoo.get_historical('2014-04-25', '2014-04-29')
```

This code thoug works once out of 4 attempts, the other 3 times gives me this errors:

```
YQL Query error: Query failed with error: No Definition found for Table yahoo.finance.quote
```

Is there anyway to fix this error so to have the code working 100% of the time?
Thanks.
Warmest regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a *server-side error*. The `query.yahooapis.com` service appears to be handled by a cluster of machines, and some of those machines appear to be misconfigured. This could be a temporary problem.

I see the same error when accessing the API directly using curl:

```
$ curl "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.quote%20where%20symbol%20%3D%20%22YHOO%22&format=json&env=store%3a//datatables.org/alltableswithkeys"
{"error":{"lang":"en-US","description":"No definition found for Table yahoo.finance.quote"}}
```

Other than retrying in a loop, there is no way to fix this on the Python side:

```
data = None
for i in range(10):  # retry 10 times
    try:
        yahoo = Share('YHOO')
        data = yahoo.get_historical('2014-04-25', '2014-04-29')
        break
    except yahoo_finance.YQLQueryError:
        continue
if data is None:
    print 'Failed to retrieve data from the Yahoo service, try again later'
```

Comment: Thanks Marijin! So i shell put it in an infinite loop till it work with try and excert?

Comment: @AmatoIlCiabattaro: exactly, perhaps with a limit on the number of times you retry.

Comment: I see the same problem when I hit the URL directly (strip out server-side code.)